# How to say "zero or more" with OWL (in Protégé)

Tags: ontology, protege

I'm a bit confused about how to make a restriction of "zero or more" in OWL (with Protégé)?

Suppose we have a Person, Order and OrderDetails class.
There is a One-to-many relation between Person and Order (but a person could also have zero orders)
An Order can have one or more OrderDetails.

The other way around an OrderDetail can only be part of one Order.
An Order can only belong to one Person.

I'm especially stuck with the zero-or-more part. Is it with min cardinality 0? Seems unintuitive. Or don't I have to do anything? and not create a restriction for zero-or-more?
I suspect that for one-or-more, I just need to use SomeValueFrom right.

Is this the following correct?

```
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#Order">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#hasParts"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#OrderDetails"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#isOrderOf"/>
            <owl:qualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:qualifiedCardinality>
            <owl:onClass rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#Person"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#OrderDetails -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#OrderDetails">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#isOrderOf"/>
            <owl:qualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:qualifiedCardinality>
            <owl:onClass rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#Order"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#Person -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#Person">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#hasOrder"/>
            <owl:minQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">0</owl:minQualifiedCardinality>
            <owl:onClass rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/ont/myMiniStore#Order"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

I'm probably thinking too much with DB relations, so any tips about one-to-one, one-to-many relations are welcome!

I really appreciate it!

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying

```
Class: Person
     SubClassOf: 
         hasOrder some Order
```

is equivalent to saying

```
Class: Person
     SubClassOf: 
         hasOrder min 1 Order
```

Adding the restriction `hasOrder min 0 Order` will have no effect. To see this think of `personA` who have zero orders and `personB` with some orders. You will for example not be able to infer that `personB` is a customer and `personA` is not.

If need be, a way that you could model this is:

```
Class: Person

Class: Customer
     SubClassOf:
         Person,
         hasOrder min 1 Order

Class: NonCustomer
     SubClassOf:
         Person,
         hasOrder max 0 Order


 Individual: personA
     Types: 
         hasOrder max 0 Order

 Individual: booksOrder
     Types:
         Order

 Individual: personB
     Facts: 
         hasOrder booksOrder
```

In this case you will be able to infer that `personB` is a customer, but to infer that `personA` is not a customer you have to explicitly state `personA` has no orders (i.e `Types: hasOrder max 0 Order`). This is where database thinking (closed world assumption) is different to Protege thinking (open world assumption). In a DB absence of information often assumes that that information does not exist whereas in Protege the assumption is that the information is just not known but may exist.

Comment: Thank you very much Henriette! Especially with the examples!
Can I still assume that I still need to "always" make the invereseOf an Object Property with the restrictions. For example one-to-many would become for the "one" I would use "exactly one" and then for the many I would use "some/someValueFrom"? Or can this be infered in another way.

Comment: As a rule of thumb I would add all constraints that I am aware of. The advantage of doing this is that the more constraints you add to your ontology the more inferences the reasoner will be able to derive from your ontology. Moreover, it will also alert you to inconsistencies in your design. So yes, I will add it. If you interested you can also have a look at my dissertation where I have written about the translation of UML to OWL and how  it can be used to increase cohesion of designs: https://henrietteharmse.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/scenariotestingusingowl_v0-1-7-final.pdf.

Comment: Fantastic! I can't thank you enough! I will definitely take a look at your blog!
I still need to get used to the "open world assumption" and how NOT use restrictions too much (or at least restrictions that aren't necessary) so others "hypothetically" could reuse the ontology since I'm just using it for academic reasons.

Comment: Henriette, maybe just to be sure if I may. In your example above where you show that "hasOrder some Order" is equivalent to "hasOrder min 1 Order". Is it not possible to NOT use "hasOrder some Order" and only "hasOrder min 0 Order". Or is this not the correct way to do it and I have to use your example of NoCustomer class.

Comment: Yes, you can have `hasOrder min 0 Order`, but it will not help you to infer anything useful and therefore the constraint is meaningless. If you want to infer something useful you have to do something like the example I have given. However, if my example does not make sense for what trying to do, you probably better of not adding further constraints.